# Laravel slug does not work - displays the same record

Tags: laravel, routes, slug

I have defined slug to view a product. The slug destination works fine but all slugs return the same product (the first one) not the one should be.

It does not show required product when I browse. It shows the first record from database. What am I missing?

**My Route**

```
Route::get('/{slug}/order', 'Controller@order')->name('order')->where('slug', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
Route::post('/{slug}/order', 'Controller@order_store')->name('order_store')->where('slug', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
Route::get('/{slug}', 'Controller@view')->name('view')->where('slug', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($slug, request $id)
{
    $item = Item::where('slug', $slug)->firstorfail()->where('status', true)->firstorfail();
    return  view ('products.show',  ['item'=>$item]);
}
```

**View Blade**

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{ route('view', $item['slug']) }}">View</a>
```

Comment: you are always returning the first item, what are you expecting it would return?

Comment: I want to display second item, if I click the ``view`` link of the second or third.item it should return the second/third item, not the first always.

Comment: then make your route to accept id also

Comment: Not sure if you can call FirstOrFail twice like that. I would remove the first FirstOrFail() call. See if that helps.

Comment: @Tuim Yes! that worked.

Comment: @universal I have added an answer, you could mark that as the answer for future reference and people coming here from search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference:

You should not call firstOrFail() twice on a query builder.

Change

```
$item = Item::where('slug', $slug)->firstorfail()->where('status', true)->firstorfail();
```

To

```
$item = Item::where('slug', $slug)->where('status', true)->firstorfail();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Route

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'Controller@view')->name('view')->where('slug', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
Route::get('/{slug}/order', 'Controller@order')->name('order')->where('slug', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
Route::post('/{slug}/order', 'Controller@order_store')->name('order_store')->where('slug', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
```

Change the Method

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $shproduct = Item::where('slug', $slug)->firstorfail()->where('status', true)->firstorfail();
    return  view ('products.show',  ['shproduct'=>$shproduct]);
}
```